# How do I remove an event listener from an button using Flash + HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, flash, canvas

Here's an example. In my HTML5 movie, at frame 100, I've added this:

```
this.stop();

this.Menu1.addEventListener("click", openCharge.bind(this));

function openCharge()
{
    this.gotoAndPlay(120);
}
```

The element **Menu1** is a button with that instance name.

However, at frame 120, I'd like to remove that event listener for my button **Menu1**.
The button won't do anything starting from frame 120.

Is that possible in Flash CC using HTML5 canvas?

How do I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: If you only want the action script to be executable in frames 1-120 you should just make your action script layer exist for frames 1-120. I think. I haven't used flash in a long time but I feel like I remember scripts only existing as long as they do on the time line or to the layer/track they are linked to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the frame try adding

```
this.Menu1.addEventListener("click", openCharge.bind(this));
```

That should hopefully do the trick. But if you want it to turn back on again at a frame make sure to do

```
this.Menu1.addEventListener("click", openCharge.bind(this));
```

So it will turn back on. Hope this helped.